# How to run Jupyter notebook and Tensorboard at the same time inside virtualenv?

Tags: tensorflow, virtualenv

I already found its workaround inside Docker. But, in my case, I am running TensorFlow inside virtualenv so that I could run my Jupyter notebook to make a code and to run it.

But I also needed to run the Tensorboard. How can I run two web application inside virtualenv? I have never run two things at the same time. If I want to, I don't know how to run it in a background.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution. Just open another shell and run virtualenv / Jupyter notebook after it is already running a Tensorboard in other shell.